# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (line 4, file "Code.gs")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get the error when I attempt to deploy the following script as a web app.

function doGet(request) {
  if(request!=null) {

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById169v40OsFOaGHO6uQwuuMx2hlWK-wvYCzrr93FAWivHk("");
```

Help!!!

Comment: You may need to provide more information and format your question a little. It's not clear what do you want to do or what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation for your API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid

You need to put your unique identifier *inside* the function call.

```
function doGet(request) {
  if(request!=null) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("169v40OsFOaGHO6uQwuuMx2hlWK-wvYCzrr93FAWivHk");
  }
}
```

Likely your error was because the function `openById169v40OsFOaGHO6uQwuuMx2hlWK-wvYCzrr93FAWivHk` is undefined. Please let us know if this solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your HTML Tag Because this error is very Confusioning error is present in Html and It shows in Code.gs at the point where you evaluate the HTML

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It’s this wvYCzrr93FAWivHk remove it, it will look like this

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById169v40OsFOaGHO6uQwuuMx2hlWK-("");
```

Run it and it should be working yes!